# App is not building due to Command EmitSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code problem

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I am new to Xcode and tried to build an app. I recently added a few of SwiftUI code into a storyboard app and it was running all well until today this problem suddenly appeared. Below is the code which is precisely shown :

```
/Users/amara/iCloud Drive (Archive) - 1/Documents/Documents - Amara’s MacBook Pro/Pomotivate/Pomotivate/PasswordChecker/NiceButtonApps.swift:10:1: error: 'main' attribute can only apply to one type in a module
```

@main
^
/Users/amara/iCloud Drive (Archive) - 1/Documents/Documents - Amara’s MacBook Pro/Pomotivate/Pomotivate/AppDelegate.swift:10:1: error: 'main' attribute can only apply to one type in a module
@main
^
Command EmitSwiftModule failed with a nonzero exit code

I tried command shift k to remove project trash, deleted excess files and restarted my laptop but none works.

Comment: upgrade your pods and spm

Comment: replace if you have (@main) to (@UIApplicationMain). or vise versa